# How to read from Azure Table Storage with a HTTP Trigger PowerShell Azure Function?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

The `Row Key` will be passed in the query string. What is needed in the function to create the "connection string" to the Table Storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that you already have an app setting in your Function App named `AzureWebJobsStorage` that has the connection string to your Table Storage, then to retrieve that value in your PowerShell script, you will add the following,

```
$connectionString = $env:AzureWebJobsStorage;
```

However, if you need to just write to Table Storage based on the row key, you could leverage the Table Storage binding that is already supported in Azure Functions.

Let's assume that there is a table named `testtable` is already created in your Table Storage and that is the table we will need to write to. Then, here's a sample setup that reads the row key from query string of an HTTP-trigger and writes an entry to Table Storage.

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "testtable",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**run.ps1:**

```
# POST method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"

Write-Output "Message entity: '$requestBody'"
$entity = [PSObject]@{
  PartitionKey = $requestBody.role  
  RowKey = $req_query_rowkey
  AccountId = $requestBody.id
}

$entity | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $outputTable
```

**Test in Postman:**

[image]

**Log view:**

```
2017-07-04T17:21:17.095 Function started (Id=775a36ce-9d71-454c-887c-05f08cfdb877)
2017-07-04T17:21:17.314 Message entity: '@{name=Azure; role=admin; id=78910}'
2017-07-04T17:21:17.314 Function completed (Success, Id=775a36ce-9d71-454c-887c-05f08cfdb877, Duration=222ms)
```

**Table entry view in Azure Storage Explorer:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Any examples on how to read from Table Storage using `$connectionString = $env:AzureWebJobsStorage` in an HTTP Trigger using PowerShell?

Comment: Excellent answer; it's so great that Microsoft devs are here writing answers like this.

Comment: @DougFinke, per our conversation over Twitter, I believe you have figured out the answer to your follow-up question on your own.

Comment: @briantist, thanks!  We strive to keep the Azure Functions community vibrant and try out best to unblock our customers  promptly.

Comment: The question is Read From table storage, but the answer is Write To table storage... I don't understand...